# Acquiring the name(or the number) of the debug info in LLVM-IR

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir

I want to print the exact number of the debug information in IR, how could I do it?

For example, consider an IR chunk as below,

```
call void @llvm.dbg.declare(metadata i32* %a, metadata !10, metadata !11), !dbg !12!
!12 = !DILocation(line: 19, column: 7, scope: !6)
```

I want to print the `!12` as a string for debugging purpose. I can acquire the object of DILocation by doing

```
Instruction::getDebugLoc()->get()
```

but all I get is a pointer and there is no such interface for acquiring the number. I can assume that LLVM gives the number when it is actually generating the bitcode,  since dumping the DILocation gives a result something like

```
<0x7342628> = !DILocation(line: 23, column: 3, scope: <0x733e5f8>)
```

this. But when I use Instruction::dump(), it gives me something that looks like

```
call void @llvm.dbg.declare(metadata i32* %a, metadata !10, metadata !11), !dbg !12
```

this, So I am confused whether it has the numbering information of a debug-info or not during runtime.

Does it have the numbering information or not? If so, how can I acquire that info? If not, where should I inspect to look for the generation of the bitcode in LLVM?

Answer (score 2):

Are you talking about line/column numbers? If so, then you can easily access them directly from the `debugLoc`:

```
instruction->getDebugLoc()->getLine()
instruction->getDebugLoc()->getColumn()
```

See the definition at `DebugInfoMetadata`:

```
unsigned getLine() const { return SubclassData32; }
unsigned getColumn() const { return SubclassData16; }
```

Comment: Not about the line and column numbers. I want to print out the  number of the debug info (in the IR) which is in this case, !12

Comment: @izazu, oh, my bad. I interpreted it as a reference to the debug info node.

Answer (score 2):

It is probably not too late to answer this question.

```
if (instruction->hasMetadata()) {
  instruction->dump();

  // one way
  SmallVector<std::pair<unsigned, MDNode *>, 4> MDs;
  instruction->getAllMetadata(MDs);
  for (auto &MD : MDs) {
    if (MDNode *N = MD.second) {
      N->printAsOperand(errs(), instruction->getModule());
      errs() << "\n";
    }
  }

  // second way
  instruction->getDebugLoc()->printAsOperand(errs(), instruction->getModule());
  errs() << "\n";

  // third way
  int debugInfoKindID = 0;
  MDNode *debug = instruction->getMetadata(debugInfoKindID);
  debug->printAsOperand(errs(), instruction->getModule());
  errs() << "\n";
}
```

Output is:

```
%11 = add nsw i32 %9, %10, !dbg !29
!29
!29
!29
```

I found this by looking at `llvm//unittests/IR/MetadataTest.cpp`, its test `TEST_F(MDNodeTest, PrintFromMetadataAsValue)`.